# Ajax Json Post Limit on PHP7 and IIS 7

Tags: php, json, ajax, highcharts

I was hoping someone could offer some help. We have a php script that produces JSON dates to load into HighCharts. For some reason the length of the JSON response is affecting it working only on the production server. We get a JSON unexpected end of content and the response is missing the final characters of the JSON response.

If we try and print 365 days it fails but 320 days works (less content), so I think it is to do with the length of the POST response. I have set all the PHP max_input_vars, POST sizes and max upload sizes etc but it is not fixing. Is there an IIS7 setting I am missing here??

**Example JSON Response:**

```
[{"name":"D","data":[{"date":"2016, 11, 26","value":0},{"date":"2016, 11, 27","value":0},{"date":"2016, 11, 28","value":83},{"date":"2016, 11, 29","value":66},{"date":"2016, 11, 30","value":92},{"date":"2016, 12, 01","value":78},{"date":"2016, 12, 02","value":78},{"date":"2016, 12, 03","value":0},{"date":"2016, 12, 04","value":0},{"date":"2016, 12, 05","value":77},{"date":"2016, 12, 06","value":88},{"date":"2016, 12, 07","value":67},{"date":"2016, 12, 08","value":116},{"date":"2016, 12, 09","value":94},{"date":"2016, 12, 10","value":0},{"date":"2016, 12, 11","value":0},{"date":"2016, 12, 12","value":111},{"date":"2016, 12, 13","value":80},{"date":"2016, 12, 14","value":75},{"date":"2016, 12, 15","value":101},{"date":"2016, 12, 16","value":57},{"date":"2016, 12, 17","value":0},{"date":"2016, 12, 18","value":0},{"date":"2016, 12, 19","value":73},{"date":"2016, 12, 20","value":35},{"date":"2016, 12, 21","value":25},{"date":"2016, 12, 22","value":0},{"date":"2016, 12, 23","value":0},{"date":"2016, 12, 24","value":0},{"date":"2016, 12, 25","value":0},{"date":"2016, 12, 26","value":0},{"date":"2016, 12, 27","value":0},{"date":"2016, 12, 28","value":0},{"date":"2016, 12, 29","value":0},{"date":"2016, 12, 30","value":0},{"date":"2016, 12, 31","value":0},{"date":"2017, 01, 01","value":0},{"date":"2017, 01, 02","value":0},{"date":"2017, 01, 03","value":52},{"date":"2017, 01, 04","value":19},{"date":"2017, 01, 05","value":17},{"date":"2017, 01, 06","value":21},{"date":"2017, 01, 07","value":0},{"date":"2017, 01, 08","value":0},{"date":"2017, 01, 09","value":29},{"date":"2017, 01, 10","value":30},{"date":"2017, 01, 11","value":21},{"date":"2017, 01, 12","value":17},{"date":"2017, 01, 13","value":30},{"date":"2017, 01, 14","value":0},{"date":"2017, 01, 15","value":0},{"date":"2017, 01, 16","value":19},{"date":"2017, 01, 17","value":23},{"date":"2017, 01, 18","value":27},{"date":"2017, 01, 19","value":24},{"date":"2017, 01, 20","value":20},{"date":"2017, 01, 21","value":0},{"date":"2017, 01, 22","value":0},{"date":"2017, 01, 23","value":31},{"date":"2017, 01, 24","value":31},{"date":"2017, 01, 25","value":22},{"date":"2017, 01, 26","value":33},{"date":"2017, 01, 27","value":20},{"date":"2017, 01, 28","value":0},{"date":"2017, 01, 29","value":0},{"date":"2017, 01, 30","value":30},{"date":"2017, 01, 31","value":33},{"date":"2017, 02, 01","value":24},{"date":"2017, 02, 02","value":32},{"date":"2017, 02, 03","value":30},{"date":"2017, 02, 04","value":0},{"date":"2017, 02, 05","value":0},{"date":"2017, 02, 06","value":26},{"date":"2017, 02, 07","value":39},{"date":"2017, 02, 08","value":41},{"date":"2017, 02, 09","value":18},{"date":"2017, 02, 10","value":24},{"date":"2017, 02, 11","value":0},{"date":"2017, 02, 12","value":0},{"date":"2017, 02, 13","value":27},{"date":"2017, 02, 14","value":31},{"date":"2017, 02, 15","value":27},{"date":"2017, 02, 16","value":25},{"date":"2017, 02, 17","value":26},{"date":"2017, 02, 18","value":0},{"date":"2017, 02, 19","value":0},{"date":"2017, 02, 20","value":30},{"date":"2017, 02, 21","value":30},{"date":"2017, 02, 22","value":24},{"date":"2017, 02, 23","value":21},{"date":"2017, 02, 24","value":19},{"date":"2017, 02, 25","value":0},{"date":"2017, 02, 26","value":0},{"date":"2017, 02, 27","value":41},{"date":"2017, 02, 28","value":26},{"date":"2017, 03, 01","value":28},{"date":"2017, 03, 02","value":36},{"date":"2017, 03, 03","value":24},{"date":"2017, 03, 04","value":0},{"date":"2017, 03, 05","value":0},{"date":"2017, 03, 06","value":43},{"date":"2017, 03, 07","value":32},{"date":"2017, 03, 08","value":29},{"date":"2017, 03, 09","value":34},{"date":"2017, 03, 10","value":18},{"date":"2017, 03, 11","value":0},{"date":"2017, 03, 12","value":0},{"date":"2017, 03, 13","value":25},{"date":"2017, 03, 14","value":36},{"date":"2017, 03, 15","value":23},{"date":"2017, 03, 16","value":32},{"date":"2017, 03, 17","value":22},{"date":"2017, 03, 18","value":0},{"date":"2017, 03, 19","value":0},{"date":"2017, 03, 20","value":39},{"date":"2017, 03, 21","value":29},{"date":"2017, 03, 22","value":34},{"date":"2017, 03, 23","value":25},{"date":"2017, 03, 24","value":22},{"date":"2017, 03, 25","value":0},{"date":"2017, 03, 26","value":0},{"date":"2017, 03, 27","value":33},{"date":"2017, 03, 28","value":27},{"date":"2017, 03, 29","value":17},{"date":"2017, 03, 30","value":26},{"date":"2017, 03, 31","value":18},{"date":"2017, 04, 01","value":0},{"date":"2017, 04, 02","value":0},{"date":"2017, 04, 03","value":36},{"date":"2017, 04, 04","value":29},{"date":"2017, 04, 05","value":21},{"date":"2017, 04, 06","value":39},{"date":"2017, 04, 07","value":29},{"date":"2017, 04, 08","value":0},{"date":"2017, 04, 09","value":0},{"date":"2017, 04, 10","value":42},{"date":"2017, 04, 11","value":41},{"date":"2017, 04, 12","value":28},{"date":"2017, 04, 13","value":18},{"date":"2017, 04, 14","value":0},{"date":"2017, 04, 15","value":0},{"date":"2017, 04, 16","value":0},{"date":"2017, 04, 17","value":0},{"date":"2017, 04, 18","value":57},{"date":"2017, 04, 19","value":28},{"date":"2017, 04, 20","value":21},{"date":"2017, 04, 21","value":17},{"date":"2017, 04, 22","value":0},{"date":"2017, 04, 23","value":0},{"date":"2017, 04, 24","value":30},{"date":"2017, 04, 25","value":26},{"date":"2017, 04, 26","value":21},{"date":"2017, 04, 27","value":29},{"date":"2017, 04, 28","value":20},{"date":"2017, 04, 29","value":0},{"date":"2017, 04, 30","value":0},{"date":"2017, 05, 01","value":0},{"date":"2017, 05, 02","value":33},{"date":"2017, 05, 03","value":29},{"date":"2017, 05, 04","value":36},{"date":"2017, 05, 05","value":29},{"date":"2017, 05, 06","value":0},{"date":"2017, 05, 07","value":0},{"date":"2017, 05, 08","value":27},{"date":"2017, 05, 09","value":35},{"date":"2017, 05, 10","value":23},{"date":"2017, 05, 11","value":26},{"date":"2017, 05, 12","value":30},{"date":"2017, 05, 13","value":0},{"date":"2017, 05, 14","value":0},{"date":"2017, 05, 15","value":31},{"date":"2017, 05, 16","value":36},{"date":"2017, 05, 17","value":28},{"date":"2017, 05, 18","value":27},{"date":"2017, 05, 19","value":18},{"date":"2017, 05, 20","value":0},{"date":"2017, 05, 21","value":0},{"date":"2017, 05, 22","value":36},{"date":"2017, 05, 23","value":29},{"date":"2017, 05, 24","value":28},{"date":"2017, 05, 25","value":40},{"date":"2017, 05, 26","value":38},{"date":"2017, 05, 27","value":0},{"date":"2017, 05, 28","value":0},{"date":"2017, 05, 29","value":0},{"date":"2017, 05, 30","value":50},{"date":"2017, 05, 31","value":15},{"date":"2017, 06, 01","value":33},{"date":"2017, 06, 02","value":20},{"date":"2017, 06, 03","value":0},{"date":"2017, 06, 04","value":0},{"date":"2017, 06, 05","value":30},{"date":"2017, 06, 06","value":33},{"date":"2017, 06, 07","value":37},{"date":"2017, 06, 08","value":31},{"date":"2017, 06, 09","value":32},{"date":"2017, 06, 10","value":0},{"date":"2017, 06, 11","value":0},{"date":"2017, 06, 12","value":38},{"date":"2017, 06, 13","value":18},{"date":"2017, 06, 14","value":29},{"date":"2017, 06, 15","value":37},{"date":"2017, 06, 16","value":30},{"date":"2017, 06, 17","value":0},{"date":"2017, 06, 18","value":0},{"date":"2017, 06, 19","value":22},{"date":"2017, 06, 20","value":27},{"date":"2017, 06, 21","value":36},{"date":"2017, 06, 22","value":29},{"date":"2017, 06, 23","value":17},{"date":"2017, 06, 24","value":0},{"date":"2017, 06, 25","value":0},{"date":"2017, 06, 26","value":32},{"date":"2017, 06, 27","value":22},{"date":"2017, 06, 28","value":30},{"date":"2017, 06, 29","value":25},{"date":"2017, 06, 30","value":28},{"date":"2017, 07, 01","value":0},{"date":"2017, 07, 02","value":0},{"date":"2017, 07, 03","value":28},{"date":"2017, 07, 04","value":23},{"date":"2017, 07, 05","value":33},{"date":"2017, 07, 06","value":30},{"date":"2017, 07, 07","value":21},{"date":"2017, 07, 08","value":0},{"date":"2017, 07, 09","value":0},{"date":"2017, 07, 10","value":18},{"date":"2017, 07, 11","value":35},{"date":"2017, 07, 12","value":25},{"date":"2017, 07, 13","value":20},{"date":"2017, 07, 14","value":30},{"date":"2017, 07, 15","value":0},{"date":"2017, 07, 16","value":0},{"date":"2017, 07, 17","value":29},{"date":"2017, 07, 18","value":24},{"date":"2017, 07, 19","value":24},{"date":"2017, 07, 20","value":29},{"date":"2017, 07, 21","value":30},{"date":"2017, 07, 22","value":0},{"date":"2017, 07, 23","value":0},{"date":"2017, 07, 24","value":23},{"date":"2017, 07, 25","value":19},{"date":"2017, 07, 26","value":35},{"date":"2017, 07, 27","value":28},{"date":"2017, 07, 28","value":10},{"date":"2017, 07, 29","value":0},{"date":"2017, 07, 30","value":0},{"date":"2017, 07, 31","value":27},{"date":"2017, 08, 01","value":22},{"date":"2017, 08, 02","value":29},{"date":"2017, 08, 03","value":20},{"date":"2017, 08, 04","value":20},{"date":"2017, 08, 05","value":0},{"date":"2017, 08, 06","value":0},{"date":"2017, 08, 07","value":24},{"date":"2017, 08, 08","value":21},{"date":"2017, 08, 09","value":22},{"date":"2017, 08, 10","value":30},{"date":"2017, 08, 11","value":22},{"date":"2017, 08, 12","value":0},{"date":"2017, 08, 13","value":0},{"date":"2017, 08, 14","value":35},{"date":"2017, 08, 15","value":26},{"date":"2017, 08, 16","value":35},{"date":"2017, 08, 17","value":24},{"date":"2017, 08, 18","value":27},{"date":"2017, 08, 19","value":0},{"date":"2017, 08, 20","value":0},{"date":"2017, 08, 21","value":31},{"date":"2017, 08, 22","value":36},{"date":"2017, 08, 23","value":31},{"date":"2017, 08, 24","value":17},{"date":"2017, 08, 25","value":19},{"date":"2017, 08, 26","value":0},{"date":"2017, 08, 27","value":0},{"date":"2017, 08, 28","value":0},{"date":"2017, 08, 29","value":36},{"date":"2017, 08, 30","value":37},{"date":"2017, 08, 31","value":82},{"date":"2017, 09, 01","value":25},{"date":"2017, 09, 02","value":0},{"date":"2017, 09, 03","value":0},{"date":"2017, 09, 04","value":28},{"date":"2017, 09, 05","value":31},{"date":"2017, 09, 06","value":25},{"date":"2017, 09, 07","value":27},{"date":"2017, 09, 08","value":28},{"date":"2017, 09, 09","value":0},{"date":"2017, 09, 10","value":0},{"date":"2017, 09, 11","value":33},{"date":"2017, 09, 12","value":34},{"date":"2017, 09, 13","value":30},{"date":"2017, 09, 14","value":30},{"date":"2017, 09, 15","value":31},{"date":"2017, 09, 16","value":0},{"date":"2017, 09, 17","value":0},{"date":"2017, 09, 18","value":35},{"date":"2017, 09, 19","value":36},{"date":"2017, 09, 20","value":21},{"date":"2017, 09, 21","value":26},{"date":"2017, 09, 22","value":29},{"date":"2017, 09, 23","value":0},{"date":"2017, 09, 24","value":0},{"date":"2017, 09, 25","value":24},{"date":"2017, 09, 26","value":26},{"date":"2017, 09, 27","value":30},{"date":"2017, 09, 28","value":38},{"date":"2017, 09, 29","value":51},{"date":"2017, 09, 30","value":0},{"date":"2017, 10, 01","value":0},{"date":"2017, 10, 02","value":31},{"date":"2017, 10, 03","value":48},{"date":"2017, 10, 04","value":73},{"date":"2017, 10, 05","value":43},{"date":"2017, 10, 06","value":33},{"date":"2017, 10, 07","value":0},{"date":"2017, 10, 08","value":0},{"date":"2017, 10, 09","value":0},{"date":"2017, 10, 10","value":0},{"date":"2017, 10, 11","value":0},{"date":"2017, 10, 12","value":0}]}]
```

Comment: I removed my answer since it's not really an answer lol, so what do you get in the log file ? it may gives us an idea on why the large response is truncated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually a PHP memory issue as the SQL query generating the date JSON, was calling too much data to process from the ajax response. Reducing the SQL query fields in the select statement fixed the issue.